# Effect of multiplier on MOSFET region of operation

Tags: pmos, current-mirror

I am designing a wide swing cascode current mirror using PMOS. In the fig attached below, M4 goes into triode when I change the multiplier value. I need to output a current that equals 50*Iref. The mirroring is also not working for some region. I've tried modifying the W/L ratios of the MOSFETs but stil I'm not able to get M4 in saturation. Moreover, I don't understand the reason why multiplier would result in such a condition. As far as my understanding, it just puts MOSFETs in parallel so that effective width can be modulated.

Edit: added images with DC operating points. The last image shows that drain voltage of M4 decreases after using multiplier.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Whenever you ask a biasing related question, you need to annotate the operating point of the transistors in your schematic and share that otherwise, it is very difficult for someone to find the issue.

Comment: @sai added the images. Please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increase the multipliers of M4, you have to increase the multipliers of M2 also. Otherwise, M4 will go into triode. If M4 goes into triode the mirroring will not happen properly any more.

Update: If you increase multiplier of M4 to 50 and do not change multiplier of M2 to 50, it will increase the VGS of M2 because current increases in M2. As you can see, originally, VGS of M2 was ~873mV and in the second case, it became 1.03V. This increase in VGS will reduce the VDS of M4 and push it into triode.

Comment: Can you provide a proper reasoning for the same?

Comment: @Arshiya, I added some explanation.